# Resizing QGIS custom form

Tags: qgis, pyqt4

I have followed [this tutorial](https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/) to create custom forms in QGIS (I work with version 2.18). However, I seem to be unable to control the shape and size of the form window. Thus, widgets are frequently out of scope or the window is oversized. Am I missing something ?